# Java project in NetBeans 8.2 is not working

Tags: 18.04, java, netbeans

I am getting thus error when trying open a new Java project in NetBeans 8.2.

[image: this is the error]

I searched and tried this solution, but it's not working.

[image]
[screenshot from tools -> option ->java.
everything else seems worling its just java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MyBCh.png)

Comment: Please review your question, no need all those capital letter.

Comment: I have NetBeans 8.2 in Ubuntu 18.04 with exactly the same results as in your 2nd screenshot and everything is working. Maybe there is something wrong with your NetBeans *Tools* -> *Options*.

Comment: i went into tools-option the screenshot will is added above

Comment: Thank you for adding the 3rd screenshot to your question. I checked your NetBeans 8.2 settings with my settings, and my settings in NetBeans 8.2 show that everything in Tools -> Options -> GUI Builder tab is the default settings, and furthermore all the tabs have selected options without any "red text" warning messages. So there is where to look to solve that error message. I'm sorry that I can't be more helpful.

Comment: Please do not [post screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your question and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: Melebius tnku friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetBeans IDE 8.2 does not support JDK 10. Go to netbeans.apache.org and install the latest release of NetBeans instead.